# No results on select

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried this for hours. I can connect to my data base and insert into it but can't seem to get anything out of it.

```
// Declarations
    $connection = mysql_connect("xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx");
    mysql_select_db("kettle_test1", $connection);
    if (!$connection)
        {
        die ('Cold not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    else
    {
    echo "connected <br> <br>";
    }



// INSERT   

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO bob2 (Danumber)
    VALUES ('32234245')");

// QUERY AND DISPLAY

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bob2");

    echo $result;

// if this is commented out I get the 'connected' message above. without it the page is blank,  
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["Danumber"];
   
}
    
*/


    echo "<br> <br> <br>";
```

Comment: Well, for one thing... $row['Danumber']; Also: try to add an if(!$result) { echo mysql_error(); } for error messages.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of possibilities here. You could try, for example, the following things:

- Use `mysql_num_rows` to check how many rows have been returned
- Use `print_r` to print the whole row.
- Use `isset` to check that the key "Danumber" actually exists

Summarizing: use a lot more checks to make sure things you retrieve are actually there.

Comment: mysql_num_rows confirms that 4 rows exist.

Comment: @Kevin: OK, so now you know that your query at least returns something. What happens if you put `print_r($row);` in the `while`?

Answer (score 0):

I would first test if inserting really went ok:

```
// INSERT   

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO bob2 (Danumber)
    VALUES ('32234245')");
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid insert query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
```

Otherwise you could not select later on. But that's probably not the cause of your problem.

But you can do the same for the `SELECT` query as well:

```
// QUERY AND DISPLAY
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bob2");
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid select query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
```

That done you can verify if the queries went through w/o errors or not at least.

Then you should ensure that you can fetch and display the data:

```
// if this is commented out I get the 'connected' message above. without it the page is blank,
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r(array_keys($row));
    print_r($row["Danumber"]);
}
```

Comment: Inserts do work. It has been tested and retest to make sure nothing has changed. I can use mysql_num_row to return a result but putting the error detection above again returns it to a blank page.

Comment: Added some code for you that should actually print something out in any case. If not, let us know.

Comment: I made the changes and still get a blank page. IT won't even print a confirmation that the database connected. As soon as I comment out the select and print it will though and inserts have been tested and work fine.

Comment: Enable PHP error reporting, display and logging to the highest level (-1). Check your php error log after recieving the white page. This should bring you closer to the error you get.